# How can I check rendered view in application.html.haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, render

Could someone please tell me how can I check rendered view in application.html.haml?

For example:

I have some view with layout for body, but header and footer are default and located in application.html.haml layout. They are (default) important for all pages except my page. And I want to replaced header and footer only for my page.

I think I should to implement some function, which will check rendered view, and if this view will be my, header and footer will be replaced to others.

But I don't know, how can I check it. Please someone help me.

Comment: you should just use another layout, which is builtin

Comment: @apneadiving , thanks a lot for move me to this solution! I've been thinking about it too!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of approaching this however as a best practice you should keep your actions as DRY as possible.

Ask the following question:

- Do I need to include any styling, scripts or images through the asset pipeline?
- Are there other pages (might be in the future) that would require a different/new layout?

If any of your answers to above questions is  "Yes" then you should add a new layout in your app/views/layouts directory and reffer to it from your controller

```
render layout: "custom_layout"
```

If your answer to both questions is "No" then you can use the same method without loading any layout:

```
render layout: false
```

With kind regards,
Dennis

Comment: Thanks Dennis! For future I will be think about these questions every time!
Thanks a lot!
Regards,
Sviat